# Using re.sub and replacing string WITH a regular expression using variables in Python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string

```
the_string = "the brown fox"
```

And I wan't to replace the spaces with a number of characters, for example, 5 dash marks

```
new_string = "the-----brown-----fox"
```

but this will be a variable, so i cant just do:

```
the_string = 'the brown fox'
new_string = re.sub(r'\s', '-----', the_string)
```

I need something like the following:

```
the_string = 'the brown fox'
num_dashes = 5
new_string = re.sub(r'\s', r'-{num_dashes}', the_string)
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Is there some reason you do not want to use [str.replace(old, new\[, count\])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)? You could write `new_string = the_string.replace(' ', '-' * num_dashes)`.

Comment: In this case that would work just fine.  Does str.replace work with a regex?  For example if I need to replace one or more spaces.  Could be one, could be multiple.

Comment: Then you are correct. You would want to use the `re` module for a variable number of whitespace characters. The `str.replace` method does not work with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
the_string = 'the brown fox'
num_dashes = 5
re.sub(r'\s', '-'*num_dashes, the_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def repl(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group():
        #do something
        #return whatever you want to replace

my_str = "the brown fox"

pattern = r"\s+"
print re.sub(pattern, repl, my_str)
```

You can define a function in `re.sub`

Comment: That's genius, THANKS A LOT